# Match according the property of an object in an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Here is my structure for one object in my collection:

```
{
  name: foo
  my_list: [
    {a:32, b:23},
    {a:12, b:31}
  ]
}
```

I'd like to get objects where the **b** of the **last** item in `my_list` match a certain value. I've tried with `$project` and `$arrayElemAt` but I don't want to change the object's structure when I return it.

Comment: It would be so much smarter to ensure your "last" array item was always "first" because you can query `"my_list.0.b": 3` without a problem. There is a `$position` modifier for that exact purpose.

Comment: It's a time series, I'll have to reverse the array to plot it. I'd prefer to keep this order.

Comment: Well make a decision. Is it more important to keep the data ordered to last for one query? Or do you actually need to do this kind of query on the latest data more? The only other option involves a full collection scan, so you simply cannot have it both ways. If you need this "latest" query, then you put the "latest" at the front of the array. Not much wriggle room on that choice.

Comment: Ok thanks, I think I will duplicate the latest b value and store it outside of the array

Comment: @Neabfi will your field `a`  always be in series?

Comment: Yes !  But it's not an index, it's just an other value.

Comment: If you control data and have flexibility of changing schema - add one more property 'last_in_the_list' and set it when you push to the array. Is it is one-off query, or you care about performance?

Comment: @Neabfi then you can do this https://mongoplayground.net/p/Qm1o34VIDGK

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $project: {
                my_list: {
                    $slice: ["$my_list", -1, 1]
                },
                name: 1
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $match: {
                'my_list.b': 31.0
            }
        },

    ]



);
```